# Update AngularJS view using model updated by AJAX

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Apologies in advance, I'm just learning AngularJS. While I can get this to actually work, I'd like to know what a better way would be to populate my view on page load using an AJAX operation:

```
module.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$routeParams', '$http', function($rootScope, $location, $routeParams, $http) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(e, current, pre) {
    console.log('Current route name: ' + $location.path());
    // Get all URL parameter
    console.log($routeParams);
    $rootScope.currentEditObject = { name: '' };
    if ($routeParams.id) {
        if ($location.path().startsWith('/object')) {
        $rootScope.type = 'object';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://localhost/getObject',
            data: {
            objectId: $routeParams.id
            }
        }).success(function(data, status) {
            $rootScope.$apply(function() { $rootScope.currentEditObject = data.response.object; });
        });

        }
    }
    });
}]);
```

I'm starting to read up on `$apply` and how it affects the digest, but I suspect there is a better practice than this. What is the "Angular way" to load the model from an AJAX request?

Comment: Get rid of that jQuery ajax call and use `$http` -- this will start a digest cycle, then simply apply the returned data to the `$scope` element which will get picked up in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed from examples I read that using `$http` meant something like this:

```
$http({
    url: '....',
    method: 'GET',
    data: {}
}).success(...
```

Doing this resolved it:

```
$http.get(url).success(successFunction)
```